# How can you change the content of a drawable image file in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, retrofit

I have an image called graph.jpg in the drawable folder, and I want to fill it with a certain image every time I download it from a server. For this, I used Retrofit, and I already have the following interface:

```
@GET("/androidimage/")
    Call<ResponseBody> getImage(
            @Query("image") String command
    );
```

And the following method in the activity:

```
 private void getImage(WebService webService, String command){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = webService.getImage(command);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    if (response.body() != null){
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
                        imageViewTouch.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                    else {
                        imageViewTouch.setImageResource(R.drawable.graph);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("LOG Error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I want my graph.jpg file to be changed to the most recent bm, converted to JPG. How can this be done?

Thanks to @Alex Klimashevsky's answer, I was able to do this using the Picasso library, and it's much simpler.

Comment: You need to store it somewhere else in the file system. The Android resources are read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for it.

This library has caching mechanism from the box.

Also you cannot replace images from `/drawable` folder.